# Kendo UI kendoWindow - Causes Javascript show function to stop working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a Kendo window created using kendoWindow, which is called on a div. This correctly shows this div in a Kendo Window. If at some later point I then try to simply show the div using the show function, to make it appear on the page instead of in a window,
 which worked perfectly fine before creating the Kendo
Window, the show doesn't work. How do I get it to show the div?

```
if (GC.ViewModels.Dashboard.IsSubscriberLoaded()) { // ***CREATES MY KENDO WINDOW
                var $kwin = $('#complaint-dashboard-container').kendoWindow({
                    width: "1400px",
                    title: "", // ??
                    modal: true,
                    actions: ["Close"]
                });
                $($kwin).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
            } else { // *** WON'T SHOW THE div if above has been executed at some point
                $('#complaint-dashboard-container').show();
            }
```

Comment: once you bind the div and make a widget it does not act as a normal div , if you need show the content i suggest you to get the html of the content and show in a different div

Comment: Thanks. You should answer this and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer : once you bind the div and make a widget it does not act as a normal div , if you need show the content i suggest you to get the html of the content and show in a different div